# Помогите разобраться с массивами python. Синтаксис

Tags: python, массивы, синтаксис

Оценки каждого из 12 учеников по трем предметам представлены в виде таблицы:

```
1  3 4 5
2  5 4 5 
.. .....
12 5 5 5
```

Необходимо ввести в программу каждую из оценок и найти их сумму. Задачу решить в двух вариантах: 1) ввод оценок осуществляется по строкам; 2) ввод оценок осуществляется по столбцам

```
s=0
a=[None]*3
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
       a[i][j]=a.append(int(input)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "8.py", line 7, in <module>
    a[i][j]=a.append(int(input))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method
```

'

Comment: В чем конкретная проблема?

Comment: я не знаю как обращаться к элементам массиву, как оформить программу дальше

Comment: Как обращаться к элементам массивам написано в каждом учебнике. Вы просите пересказать вам учебник?

Comment: я прошу показать мне элементарный пример на задаче

Comment: если вам сложно, буду признательна, если лично вы просто проигнорите  мой вопрос, спасибо,

Comment: Здесь не показывают элементарных примеров на задаче и не решают задач вместо вас. Есть конкретная проблема - задавайте конкретный вопрос.

Comment: `print(a[0][0])` -- обращение, `a[0][0] = 1` установка значения. И кст, в `range(1,4)` проблема -- т.к. индексы начинаются с 0, а не 1, поэтому сделайте так: `range(3)`. Плюс, у вас отступы неравномерные, делайте их по 4 пробела

Comment: Вам же в трейсбеке пишет, что нет так. Вы пытаетесь сделать `a[i][j]=a.append(int(input)`, но `input` это метод, т.е. вы пытаетесь метод явно привести к `int`, отсюда и ошибка. Правильно будет `a[i][j]=a.append(int(input())`

Comment: исправила все равно ошибка только другая 5 5 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "8.py", line 7, in <module>
    a[i][j]=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5 5 4'

Comment: @Leila Опять-таки, вам всё пишет. "Не могу конвертировать строку в число: '5 5 4'". И ведь всё правильно. "5 5 4" это не число, это 3 числа. Для этого уже нужен другой подход. У вас, собственно, даже матрица неправильно инициализирована. gil9red дал вам хороший код. Ещё интересует, что значит: "Необходимо ввести в программу каждую из оценок и найти их сумму". Найти сумму абсолютно всех оценок? Или оценок каждого ученика? Или оценок по каждому предмету?

Answer (score 1):

Пример создания матрицы, заполнения ее и вывода.

Суммирование, думаю, сами осилите :)

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix, 1):
        print('{}. {}'.format(i, ', '.join(map(str, row))))

    print()


# Количество учеников
N = 3

# Количество предметов
M = 3

# Матрица оценок
ratings = [[0] * M for _ in range(N)]
print_matrix(ratings)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        value = int(input('Введите оценку для {} ученика, для {} предмета: '.format(i + 1, j + 1)))
        ratings[i][j] = value

print_matrix(ratings)
```

Консоль:

```
1. 0, 0, 0
2. 0, 0, 0
3. 0, 0, 0

Введите оценку для 1 ученика, для 1 предмета: 1
Введите оценку для 1 ученика, для 2 предмета: 2
Введите оценку для 1 ученика, для 3 предмета: 3
Введите оценку для 2 ученика, для 1 предмета: 4
Введите оценку для 2 ученика, для 2 предмета: 5
Введите оценку для 2 ученика, для 3 предмета: 6
Введите оценку для 3 ученика, для 1 предмета: 7
Введите оценку для 3 ученика, для 2 предмета: 8
Введите оценку для 3 ученика, для 3 предмета: 9
1. 1, 2, 3
2. 4, 5, 6
3. 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
students = 12 #Кол-во учеников
lessons = 3 #Кол-во предметов
marks = [] #Будущая таблица оценок
#Заполняем по строкам
for i in range(students):
    row = input() #Получаем строку оценок
    row = row.split() #Получаем список оценок (элементы списка всё ещё не числа, а строки)
    row = list(map(int, row)) #"Переделываем" строки (например, "42") в числа (42)
    marks.append(row) #Вносим в таблицу строку оценок для i-го ученика
#Стоит учитывать, что здесь никак не проверяется, сколько Вы ввели оценок

#Заполняем по столбцам
marks = [[] for i in range(students)] #Тут мы как бы заранее говорим, сколько будет строк
for i in range(lessons):
    col = input() #Получаем столбец оценок в виде строки
    col = col.split() #Аналогично разбиваем строку оценок на список отдельных оценок
    col = list(map(int, col)) #"Переводим" строки в числа
    for i in range(len(col)):
        marks[i].append(col[i]) #Добавляем в список оценок i-го предмета i-ую введённую оценку
#Опять-таки не проверяется, что ввёл пользователь
#Считаем сумму абсолютно всех оценок
total_marks = 0
for row in marks: #Для каждой строки таблицы
    for mark in row: #Для каждой оценки из строки
        total_marks += mark
```

Не гарантирую, что этот код сработает если его копировать и вставить, привёл просто для понимания.